# Is there anyway to put videoCapture(0)(from python file) in C# user interface

Tags: python, user-interface, visual-studio-2019

I'm doing project about face-recognition. 
I'm studying about creating user interface using C# in Visual Studio 2019

I want to know how can I put real-time video output from `videoCapture.py` to C# user interface

Here is the code in `videoCapture.py`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is namespace code of UI

```
namespace DropDownMenu
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var menuReceptionist = new List<SubItem>();
            menuReceptionist.Add(new SubItem("Profiles", new UserControlAdd()));
            var item0 = new ItemMenu("Receptionist", menuReceptionist, PackIconKind.ViewDashboard);

            var menuAdmin = new List<SubItem>();
            menuAdmin.Add(new SubItem("Admins Profile", new UserControlAdmins()));
            menuAdmin.Add(new SubItem("Add Admin", new UserControlAdd()));
            var item1 = new ItemMenu("Administrations", menuAdmin, PackIconKind.FaceProfile);

            var menuPreprocess = new List<SubItem>();
            menuPreprocess.Add(new SubItem("New Data", new UserControlAdmins()));
            var item2 = new ItemMenu("Data PreProcessing", menuPreprocess, PackIconKind.Schedule);

            Menu.Children.Add(new UserControlMenuItem(item0, this));
            Menu.Children.Add(new UserControlMenuItem(item1, this));
            Menu.Children.Add(new UserControlMenuItem(item2, this));
        }

        internal void SwitchScreen(object sender)
        {
            var screen = ((UserControl)sender);

            if(screen!=null)
            {
                StackPanelMain.Children.Clear();
                StackPanelMain.Children.Add(screen);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();
            win1.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I do anything wrong, I am sorry in advance. This is my first time posting in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your python script from c# which can be done through a couple of methods. Here's an article explaining the process:

[Running Python Script From C# and Working With the Results](https://medium.com/better-programming/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
//add library 
using Emgu.CV;

// in your code 

VideoCapture _videoCapture = new VideoCapture ();

// to process frames
Application.Idle += ProcessFrame ; // you should create this function
```

Thats it
I have made a video to explain in simple code how to detect and recognize faces

You can check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEpSdKoyhs0